# java spring constructor injection with parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

So this is a sample dependency class. This is just an example to show you here:

```
package com.apress.prospring5.ch3;
public class Dependency {
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Dependency{}"; }
}
```

This dependency is used here. At the moment the Dependency class is using the default constructor:

```
package com.apress.prospring5.ch3;

public class ConstructorInjection {

    private Dependency dependency;

    public ConstructorInjection(Dependency dependency) {
        System.out.println("-> Injecting Dependency in ConstructorInjection()");
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "ConstructorInjection{" +
           "dependency=" + dependency +
           '}';
    }
```

}

I am using Java Spring 5 for this example so using XML-based context configuration for the moment
My context is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dependency" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch3.Dependency"/>
    <bean id="consInj" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch3.ConstructorInjection"
          c:dependency-ref="dependency">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here I provide an example of using the above code with public static void main
The main function is here:

```
package com.apress.prospring5.ch3;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class ConInjDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("app-context-xml.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        ConstructorInjection ci = ctx.getBean("consInj", ConstructorInjection.class);
        System.out.println(ci);
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I modify the code if the Dependency class is like this:

```
    package com.apress.prospring5.ch3;

    public class Dependency {
        private String name;

        public Dependency(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return "Dependency{"+ this.name +"}"; }
    }
```

I should probably use something like that:

```
 <constructor-arg type="int">
    <value>90</value> 
 </constructor-arg>
```

but don't know how to adapt this to my example

Comment: In your dependency bean, in your config, you'll have to add a parameter name of type String.

Comment: how should it look like then?

Comment: I am struggling to use something like:  <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>90</value> 
        </constructor-arg>

Comment: well, that won't do, since you are expecting a String, not an int

Comment: please could you post the new XML beans?

Comment: If you look at what you have as "something like", and you know it needs to be a String object, how do you think it should look like?

Comment: Going over this link should solve your problem: https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: that example doesn't show a dependency between engine and transmission... don't know how it relates to this post...

Comment: that link shows exactly what you need to add in your config. an example from that link: <bean id="transmission" class="com.baeldung.constructordi.domain.Transmission">
    <constructor-arg value="sliding"/>
</bean> All you need, is how to configure the parameter for the constructor, all the rest, you already have.

Comment: I see now.. I should modify the Dependency bean instead of the ConstructorInjection bean.. let me try it now thanks for your help